# How to use oauthorizer in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, firefox-addon

I am trying to use `oauth2` in Firefox, and I found this module from Google:

https://github.com/mozilla/oauthorizer

However, I am not sure how to use it.

I tried the following according to `README` of the project,

```
Components.utils.import("resource://oauthorizer/modules/oauthconsumer.js");
```

Yet it reports error of following:

> "`Components` is not available in this context.Functionality provided by Components may be available in an SDKmodule: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK However, if you still need to import Components, you may use the`chrome` module's properties for shortcuts to Component properties:Shortcuts:     Cc = Components.classes     Ci = Components.interfaces     Cu = Components.utils     CC = Components.Constructor Example:     let { Cc, Ci } = require('chrome');"

Then, I tried this:

```
let {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://oauthorizer/modules/oauthconsumer.js");
```

But I got this error then:

> "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
>   [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]"

May be I need to set up something in the package.json? Or there are some special mechanisms to import the external modules?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I think it might not work with Cu.import you may have to use `loadSubScript`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIJSSubScriptLoader here are some examples: https://github.com/search?l=javascript&q=oauthconsumer.js&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: thanks for the hint of searching the github, I would take further look of the examples.

Comment: I actually have a need for this too, I have to save images to google drive for my addon, if you figure out more please share. I will be looking into this soon. I didn't know mozilla had an oauth module so this is really cool!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this is what I did: (Please note that I used [jpm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_(jpm)) for the addon development)

1. Install oauthorizer using `npm`. Inside the root folder of addon, run the following:

`npm install oauthorizer --save`

2. In the addon script (`index.js`), add the following:

```js
var OAuthConsumer = require("oauthorizer/lib/oauthconsumer.js").OAuthConsumer;
```

3. Modify the `oauthconsumer.js` a little bit to update the path:

e.g. replace `require("sha1")` to `require("./sha1")`

I am pretty sure it's **not** the best solution, but at least it works.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing!! I'll share with you how I end up using it :)